# Parse Javascript SDK query: Combining two queries using AND

Tags: parse-platform

I have a class named `Event`, it has a column named `end_time` of type Date and a column named `title` of type String. I would like to fetch the events whose `end_time` column is either undefined or is greater than or equal to `new Date()`. This is not difficult as it can be done with the following code:

```
var query1 = new Parse.Query(Event);
var query2 = new Parse.Query(Event);
query1.doesNotExist("end_time");
query2.greaterThanOrEqualTo("end_time", new Date());

var query1And2 = Parse.Query.or(query1, query2);
```

`query1And2` can correctly return the results I want. However, the problem is if I add one more constrain like: given a user specified title, return the events whose title is either undefined or equals user specified title. This constrain is not difficult to construct in its own, like:

```
var query3 = new Parse.Query(Event);
var query4 = new Parse.Query(Event);
query3.doesNotExist("title");
query4.equalTo("title", userTitle);

var query3And4 = Parse.Query.or(query3, query4);
```

but, how can I query `Event` with both `query1And2` and `query3And4`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These constraints can be achieved with a little boolean math.  It looks like you already understand that parse allows you to specify conjunctive (and) constraints on a single query and disjunctive (or) constraints by combining multiple queries with `Query.or()`**.  So to get the constraints you're aiming for, we need to transform your query logic to disjucntive form.

Your individual predicates are:

```
A = doesNotExist("end_time")
B = greaterThanOrEqualTo("end_time", new Date())
C = doesNotExist("title")
D = equalTo("title", userTitle)
```

and we wish to produce the query:

```
(A or B) and (C or D)
```

Rewriting this product of sums as a sum of products using algebra, we get:

```
= (A and C) or (B and C) or (A and D) or (B and D)
=    q0     or    q1     or    q2     or    q3
```

where q0..q3 are queries constrained by ANDed constraints.  Rendering those as code:

```
var q0 = new Parse.Query(Event);
q0.doesNotExist("end_time");
q0.doesNotExist("title");

var q1 = new Parse.Query(Event);
q1.greaterThanOrEqualTo("end_time", new Date());
q1.doesNotExist("title");

var q2 = new Parse.Query(Event);
q2.doesNotExist("end_time");
q2.equalTo("title", userTitle);

var q3 = new Parse.Query(Event);
q3.greaterThanOrEqualTo("end_time", new Date());
q3.equalTo("title", userTitle);

var querySum = Parse.Query.or(q0, q1, q2, q3);
```

** Query.or() probably just runs those queries separately they way we would with Promise.when() and combines the results, but lets assume that parse does a better job at this than we can at the app level.